# Does an Inquisitor prestige class exist in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, prestige-class

Is there a prestige class specifically for inquisitors in Pathfinder? I know there is for alchemists, but I can't seem to find one for inquisitors.

Comment: The term "specifically for inquisitors" is a kind of broad. Do you mean prestige classes that *require* a certain Inquisitor level or classes feature?  Or can this include prestige classes that synergize with Inquisitor features, but may be taken by other classes?

Comment: @MikeQ I think answers might want to address that. That is, the question implies that prestige classes are *for* certain classes when, in fact, they're simply *available* to any creature that meets the prestige class's requirements. Puckett, I don't want answers to sound condescending, so, if I may, are you new to *Pathfinder* and similar d20 games that use the prestige class concept?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Some prestige classes (e.g. Master Chymist, Winter Witch) have prerequisites that are exclusive to certain classes. The asker has several recent questions asking whether something exists in Pathfinder; I suspect they're asking for Inquisitor-exclusive prestige classes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MikeQ Aha. I was thrown off by Puckett's rep—a score of around 100 usually indicating a new user here but from a different stack—and didn't realize the user'd asked other *Pathfinder* questions. My apologies. I agree that the question currently *sounds* like a request for prestige classes that only an for inquisitor meets the requirements of, but it *also* sounds like—to me, anyway—a fundamental misread of the *idea* of prestige classes. Because the former's easy yet the latter complicated, I'd really like Puckett to clarify a little.